Area of the triangle inside the triangle

Area of each shape in the triangle is written. What is the area of the
shaded region?


Based on my search, $\dfrac{S_{\triangle MNP}}{S_{\triangle ABC}}$ can be calculated by Routh's Theorem. assuming $S_{\triangle MNP}= x$, using the notation in the linked site, we have $r=\dfrac{25}{x+34}$ and $s=t=\dfrac{30}{x+29}$. And,
$$\dfrac{S_{\triangle MNP}}{S_{\triangle ABC}}= \dfrac{(rst-1)^2}{(rs+r+1)(st+s+1)(tr+t+1)}$$
But substituting these value in the given formula leads to a tedious equation which I believe is very hard to solve for $x$.
I've also noticed that $\dfrac{FM}{BM}= \dfrac8{17}$ and $\dfrac{EN}{CN}=\dfrac8{22}$ and $\dfrac{PD}{PA}=\dfrac{10}{20}$. But I'm not sure how to continue.
Edit:
Using Mathematica, to solve for $x$ I got this result,

The positive real root is $0.138\ldots$, which is consistent with dan_fulea's result.

You essentially derive the proof of Routh's. We have $8/17 = FM/MB = FA / (AF + FC) * CD/DB$, so can express it via ratio of sides, and figure them out.

Which is the source of the problem, or at least of the original image? (The two areas that are marked $12$ have no optical chance to be equal...) I typed something, and also tried to make the numbers work in a picture, and it turns out that the area in the middle is something like $0.1384604266794964\dots$ - so the picture is completely misleading.

@dan_fulea At least, you are getting a positive answer. I’m getting $-1.7836962…$

@dan_fulea I've found this problem with its picture in a geometry group in Telegram. And I agree that the picture is very misleading. Now I wrote the Mathematica code to find the $x$ using Routh's theorem and as you mentioned the positive real root I got is $0.138.... $ I'll edit my post to include this.

@dan_fulea FYI, as I show in my answer, I also determined a rather small result, but it's somewhat larger than what you got. I've checked my calculations several times (and will do it again), so I don't understand why it's different from yours, along with the OP's confirming result.

I also solved the Routh’s equation in Wolfram and got $0.138…$. But the fact that this equation has a root doesn’t guarantee that the picture exists! I am pretty sure that this picture doesn’t exist, that’s why different methods lead to different answers.

This problem is, as it comes to the reader, intriguing for more reasons. It is based on a figure, which is with intention a bad figure, so that the solver has no useful information from it, except for the data about the areas. This answer tried in a first version only to realize such a picture. However, it turns out that the given areas, in some cyclic order $8,12,10,12,8,9$, have no chance to appear so. This may be a good point to stop, however i decided to go further. Some of the six values can be computed when the others are given. Removing the one or the other given value from the list then leads to solutions. But to avoid ugly typing, i decided to remove the information that leads to a solvable, nice (symmetric) situation. This situation is not important per se, but shows what is in fact needed to have a problem. It also explains why there are so many solutions showing that the given geometric constellation is impossible.
Imagine for a second that instead of
$$
8,\ 
12,\ 
10,\ 
12,\ 
8,\ 
9,\ 
$$
the problem gives:
$$
8,\ 
12,\ 
(?),\ 
12,\ 
8,\ 
(?)\ . 
$$
Can we solve this problem? What kind of solution do we have? Also, when geometry is "made explicit" it is always better than a general solution. (For instance, we have some numbers, apply - as i did in the comments - one theorem, this gives a number. So this is the solution... Indeed?! Any geometric intuition?! Why not explicitly realize this solution? So that we see it is part of the real life, and we see the relation between the numbers, e.g. how big or small the area "in the middle" really can be.)
With this plan in mind, a long answer crystallized step by step, well, i was in the mood to "draw" a lot for my own curiosity. So the answer is long, but at least maybe not dry at any place, a lot of pictures serve for orientation. Computations were delegated to the engine, sage is my choice this days.


First of all, there is a difference between the pictures and the formulas

in the AoPS link, and respectively
on the wiki page, which is mentioned with the proof in the AoPS link.

Below i will go with the wiki picture, because the marked triangle from this link, and from the present problem are have matching half-planes.
Let $A$ be the question mark area from the posted problem.
With the notations from the wiki page, as in the picture

we obtain then, with the "same placement" of the sides:
$$
x = \frac{34+A}{25}\ ,\qquad
y=z=\frac{29+A}{30}\ .
$$
The total area of the triangle is $59+A$. Routh's Theorem then leads to an algebraic equation in $A$, considering $x,y,z$ from above as affine functions in $A$:
$$\tag{*}
\frac A{59+A}
=
\frac{(xyz-1)^2}
{(xy+y+1)(yz+z+1)(zx+x+1)}
\ .
$$
We solve this equation in algebraic numbers, i.e. in the field $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ aided by sage, the code is simple:
R.<A> = PolynomialRing(QQbar)
x, y, z = (34 + A)/25, (29 + A)/30, (29 + A)/30
eq = A/(59+A) - (x*y*z - 1)^2 / (x*y + y + 1) / (y*z + z + 1) /(z*x + x + 1)
eq = eq.numerator() / 2

And so we have the equation satisfied by $A$, explicitly eq$=0$ where eqis:
sage: eq
13*A^6 + 3497*A^5 + 381095*A^4 + 21482265*A^3 + 630191470*A^2 + 7824603322*A - 1095536662

Which (complex) values for $A$ are possible?
sage: eq.roots(multiplicities=False)
[-89.8018249983995?,
 0.1384604266794964?,
 -45.0626264540228? - 24.7250362782332?*I,
 -45.0626264540228? + 24.7250362782332?*I,
 -44.6056912601172? - 23.9932083918389?*I,
 -44.6056912601172? + 23.9932083918389?*I]

Only two real values remain in discussion. Well, the value
$$
A = 0.1384604266794964\dots
$$
must be working, so we must be able to realize the situation! So i tried to manufacture the corresponding picture in geogebra, since we have all we need.
From now on, $A$ is no longer a variable, but the one exact real positive root of the mentioned polynomial eq above (near $0.13846\dots$).
sage: A = eq.roots(multiplicities=False)[1]
sage: A
0.1384604266794964?

Note that sage works with an exact number.
The total area is $59+A$, and the side $a$ of an equilateral triangle with this area is:
sage: a = QQbar(sqrt(4*(59 + A)/sqrt(3)))
sage: a
11.68650607269828?
sage: a.n(150)
11.686506072698278932893307558220881606371837

(and we can get more decimals, if we really want to...)
After having the value of $A$ everything is then determined.
So we draw in geogebra an equilateral triangle with size $a$, and compute all the points needed in the picture, the ones on the size first, this time with some reality touch (maybe). And here is the figure we obtain:

Yes, the area in the middle is exactly the area we wanted!
But all the other data is scrambled! In other words, the picture does not exist, there are further constrains that have to be satisfied. Simply putting random numbers in (all other) regions does not lead to a living geometric configuration!

It turns out that if we give the points $D,E,F$ on the sides $BC,CA,AB$ of the triangle $\Delta ABC$, so that they build proportions $1:x$, $1:y$, and $1:z$ on the delimited segments as shown in the following picture...

Then we also have a known position of each of the points $M,N,P$ on the two corresponding segments each of them is living on. For instance, completely ignoring signs:

$\displaystyle 1
=\frac{MF}{MC}\cdot \frac{EC}{EA}\cdot \frac{BA}{BF}
=\frac{MF}{MC}\cdot \frac 1y\cdot \frac{z+1}z$, and
$\displaystyle 1
=\frac{ME}{MB}\cdot \frac{FB}{FA}\cdot \frac{CA}{CE}
=\frac{ME}{MB}\cdot \frac z1\cdot \frac{y+1}1
$ .

Then with the notations $S,T,U;s,t,u;X$ for the delimited areas we have a lot of relations:
$$\tag{$\dagger$}$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x(S+t+T) &= X + s + u+U\ ,\\
y(T+u+U) &= X + t + s+S\ ,\\
z(U+s+S) &= X + u + t+T\ ,\\[2mm]
\frac{T+u}{t+X} &=\frac {MC}{MF}=\frac {z+1}{yz}\ ,\\
\frac{T+u}{U}   &=\frac {MB}{ME}=\frac {z(y+1)}1\ ,\qquad\text{ and similarly}\\[2mm]
\frac{U+s}{u+X} &=\frac {NA}{ND}=\frac {x+1}{zx}\ ,\\
\frac{U+s}{S}   &=\frac {NC}{NF}=\frac {x(z+1)}1\ ,
\\[2mm]
\frac{S+t}{s+X} &=\frac {PB}{PE}=\frac {y+1}{xy}\ ,\\
\frac{S+t}{T}   &=\frac {PA}{PD}=\frac {y(x+1)}1\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
So there are many relations. We may want to eliminate for instance the variables $x,y,z;X$, thus obtaining relations for the remained variables, which denote given areas in our problem.
It turns out, that when we declare the four regions
$$8,\ 8,\ 12,\ 12$$
from the initial picture, then a lot can be said about the rest.
Let us solve this problem(s) instead.



Alternative Problem I: Which are the possibilities for the reddish areas in the figure:




Solving those equations goes beyond my purpose, so the job is postponed, in the appendix there is a code section showing that the only possibility is that the remained pieces also have the values $8,12$, so that we have a symmetric picture.
$\square$


So we obtain a more specific alternative version, the only possible one:

Alternative Problem II: Which is the red area in the following figure?




We have finally a configuration that we can solve.
Let $X$ be the red area. We come back to the first picture, the one from the wiki page. In that notations we have now $x=y=z=(32+X)/28$. The equation we write is setting equal the proportion $X/(60+X)$ (red area versus whole area), and the proportion from Routh's theorem $(xyz-1)^2/\prod(xy+y+1)=(x^3-1)^2/(x^2+x+1)^3=(x-1)^2/(x^2+x+1)$.
Then $\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-2x+1}=\frac {60+X}X$, which implies
$\frac{3x}{(x-1)^2}=\frac {60}X$. After some computations we obtain the equation of second degree in $X$ (to be solved in positive real numbers)
$X^2 +92X-40=0$, and this gives
$$X=14\sqrt {11}-46\approx 0.4327470649756\dots\ ,$$
again a small number, but a valid number.
Can we realize this final configuration in geogebra?
Yes, up to some precision, the situation is confirmed:

$\square$



Appendix: (Code section)
The following code determines the possibilities for the values of $T$, when the values for $S,t,u,U$ are given to be respectively $8,12,12,8$. It collects the established relations between $x,y,z;S,T,U;s,t,u;X$, and connects them with these special values. We eliminate some variables, till an equation for $T$ is obtained:
R.<x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X> = PolynomialRing(QQ)

def eq1(x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X):    return -x*(S+t+T) + (X+s+u+U) 
def eq2(x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X):    return -y*z*(T+u) + (z+1)*(t+X) 
def eq3(x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X):    return -(T+u) + z*(y+1)*U 

J = R.ideal([eq1(x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X),
             eq1(y,z,x,T,U,S,t,u,s,X),
             eq1(z,x,y,U,S,T,u,s,t,X),
             eq2(x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X),
             eq2(y,z,x,T,U,S,t,u,s,X),
             eq2(z,x,y,U,S,T,u,s,t,X),
             eq3(x,y,z,S,T,U,s,t,u,X),
             eq3(y,z,x,T,U,S,t,u,s,X),
             eq3(z,x,y,U,S,T,u,s,t,X),
             S-8, t-12, u-12, U-8])

K = J.elimination_ideal([x, y, z, X, S, t, u, U, s])
print(K.gens()[0].factor())

And the above is equivalent to solving the system $(\dagger)$, where
we moreover set the values for $S,t,u,U$. It delivers:
(T - 8) * (T + 12) * (T + 20)

So there are only three possibilities for $T$. (We still have to check if they are possible in our real world.) For each of the possibilities we ask for the corresponding $s$-value. For $T=8$ we obtain the value imposed by symmetry:
K8 = R.ideal(J.gens() + [T - 8])
K8.elimination_ideal([x, y, z, X, S, t, u, U, T]).gens()[0]

This gives the relation $s-12$, so the value for $s$ is $12$.
Then
K12 = R.ideal(J.gens() + [T - 12])
K12.elimination_ideal([x, y, z, X, S, t, u, U, T]).gens()[0]

gives $1$, i.e. $1=0$, this is impossible. And finally
K20 = R.ideal(J.gens() + [T - 20])
K20.elimination_ideal([x, y, z, X, S, t, u, U, T]).gens()[0]

also shows the $1$, i.e. the equation $1=0$ is again a consequence,
again an impossible case. This means that only $T=8$ and $s=12$ is possible.

Join $A$ to $N$, and let
$$S_{\triangle AEN} = y \;\;\to\;\; S_{\triangle AMN} = 9 - y$$
Using that the ratio of base lengths of triangles with the same altitudes is the same as their ratio of areas, we get
$$\frac{S_{\triangle AEN}}{S_{\triangle BEN}} = \frac{S_{\triangle AEC}}{S_{\triangle BEC}} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{y}{8} = \frac{x + 29}{30}\;\;\to\;\; y = \frac{4x}{15} + \frac{116}{15}$$
There's also
$$\frac{S_{\triangle AFN}}{S_{\triangle CFN}} = \frac{S_{\triangle AFB}}{S_{\triangle CFB}} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{8 + (9 - y)}{x + 12} = \frac{25}{x + 34}\;\;\to\;\; (17 - y)(x + 34) = 25(x + 12)$$
Substituting the result for $y$ in the previous equation and simplifying gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(17 - \left(\frac{4x}{15} + \frac{116}{15}\right)\right)(x + 34) & = 25x + 300 \\
\left(-\frac{4x}{15} + \frac{139}{15}\right)(x + 34) & = 25x + 300 \\
(-4x + 139)(x + 34) & = 15(25x + 300) \\
-4x^2 + 3x + 4726 & = 375x + 4500 \\
-4x^2 - 372x + 226 & = 0 \\
x^2 + 93x - 56.5 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Using the quadratic formula, and that $x \gt 0$, we get
$$x = \frac{-93 + \sqrt{93^2 - 4(-56.5)}}{2} = \frac{-93 + \sqrt{8875}}{2} \approx 0.6036$$
As indicated in dan_fulea's comment (of an even smaller positive result) and Aig's comment (about actually getting a relatively small negative result instead), this value also doesn't match what's indicated in the diagram particularly well.

There is no solution to this problem. In order to show that, let's adjust a bit the figure: as shear mappings preserve areas, we can apply suitable shears to transform $MNP$ into an equilateral triangle with side $l$. Moreover, we can scale the figure so that $l=1$: that will change all areas by a factor $1/l^2$, but will preserve the ratio of areas.
Let's set then (see figure below):
$$
PC=x,\quad NB=y,\quad MA=z.
$$
The area of triangle $CNB$ can then be computed as
${\sqrt3\over4}(x+1)y$, and analogous formulas hold for $BMA$ and $APC$. We can then write two equations for the ratios of these areas:
$$
{(x+1)y\over 22}={(y+1)z\over 17}={(z+1)x\over 20}.
$$
Let's set now
$$
PD=t,\quad NE=u,\quad MF=v.
$$
These lengths are functions of $x$, $y$, $z$. To find the relation for $t$, note that the area of $CNB$ is the sum of the areas of $CPD$ and $DPNB$, leading to the equation
$$
{\sqrt3\over4}(x+1)y={\sqrt3\over4}xt+{\sqrt3\over4}((t+1)(y+1)-1),
$$
which can be solved to:
$$
t={xy\over x+y+1}
\quad\text{and analogously:}\quad
u={yz\over y+z+1},\quad
v={zx\over z+x+1}.
$$
We can then find two more equations from the ratios of triangles $CPD$, $BNE$ and $AMF$:
$$
{xt\over10}={yu\over8}={zv\over8}.
$$
This makes a total of four equations for three unknowns $x,y,z$.
I tried to solve this system with Mathematica and got only the trivial solution $x=y=z=0$. Hence the given areas are not consistent with the existence of triangle $MNP$.


$\newcommand{\f}{\frac} \newcommand{\c}{\cdot} \newcommand{\l}{\left(} \newcommand{\r}{\right)}$ I think, something is wrong with this problem. I’m getting that this picture doesn’t exist, because $x$ must be negative. We have
$$\f{FM}{BM}=\f8{8+9}=\f8{17},$$
$$\f{EN}{CN}=\f8{10+12}=\f4{11},$$
$$\f{PD}{PA}=\f{10}{12+8}=\f12.$$
Applying Menelaus’ theorem to line $A-M-D$ and triangle $FBC$, we have that $$\f{FA}{CA}\cdot\f{CD}{BD}\cdot\f{BM}{FM}=1$$
$$\f{FA}{CF+FA}\cdot\f{CD}{BD}\cdot\f{17}{8}=1$$
$$\f{1}{\f{CF}{FA}+1}\cdot\f{CD}{BD}=\f{8}{17}.$$
Applying Menelaus’ theorem to line $B-N-F$ and triangle $ECA$, we have that $$\f{EN}{CN}\cdot\f{CF}{AF}\cdot\f{AB}{EB}=1$$
$$\f{4}{11}\cdot\f{CF}{AF}\cdot\f{AE+EB}{EB}=1$$
$$\f{CF}{AF}\cdot\left(\f{AE}{EB}+1\right)=\f{11}4.$$
Applying Menelaus’ theorem to line $C-P-E$ and triangle $DAB$, we have that $$\f{DP}{AP}\cdot\f{AE}{BE}\cdot\f{BC}{DC}=1$$
$$\f{1}{2}\cdot\f{AE}{BE}\cdot\f{BD+DC}{DC}=1$$
$$\f{AE}{BE}\c\left(\f{BD}{DC}+1\right)=2.$$
Denote $\f{AE}{BE}$ by $u$, $\f{BD}{CD}$ by $v$, $\f{CF}{AF}$ by $w$. Then we have the following system of equations:
$$\left\{\begin{align}
u(v+1)&=2\\
v(w+1)&=\f{17}8\\
w(u+1)&=\f{11}4
.\end{align}\right.$$
We have $u=\f2{v+1}$, $w=\f{17}{8v}-1$ from the first two equations. The third one then becomes $$\left(\f{17}{8v}-1\right)\c\l\f2{v+1}+1\r=\f{11}4$$
$$\left(\f{17-8v}{8v}\right)\c\l\f{v+3}{v+1}\r=\f{11}4$$
$$(17-8v)\c(v+3)=22\c(v^2+v)$$
$$17v-8v^2+51-24v=22v^2+22v$$
$$30v^2+29v-51=0$$
$$v=\f{-29+\sqrt{29^2+120\c51}}{60}=\f{\sqrt{6961}-29}{60}.$$
At the same time, $$v=\f{BD}{CD}=\f{S_{ABD}}{S_{ACD}}=\f{x+9+8+12}{8+12+10}=\f{x+29}{30}.$$
Hence $$x=30v-29= \f{\sqrt{6961}-29}{2}-29= \f{\sqrt{6961}-87}{2}.$$
